# c++ assign the value of the user input into another variable and swap the value everything it get loop

Tags: c++

i think i could get a little help from you guys, so i'm trying to swap swap the player's name that i get it from user input. I try to assign the value of one of the player's name into variable current_name_turn. So, everytime it get loop through, the current_name_turn will change the value into the other player's name whether using if condition or swap, i could use both. but here seems like my current_name_turn's value is not being casted out. or maybe i fail to pass the value into it. So, i need a correction or suggestion please :)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool game_is_playing = true;
string name[] = {"x","o"};
string player_1, player_2;
string current_name_turn = player_1;

string ask_player_name_1(string player_1){
    cout << " Player 1's name: ";
    cin >> name[0];
    player_1 = name[0];
    return player_1;
}

string ask_player_name_2(string player_2){
    cout << " Player 2's name: ";
    cin >> name[1];
    player_2 = name[1];
    return player_2;
}

void display_board(){
    cout << player_1 + " (X) - (O) " + player_2 << endl;
}

void player_turn(){
    int position;
    cin.clear();
    cout << current_name_turn << "'s turn." << endl;
    cout << "Enter something: " << endl;
    cin << position;
}

void switch_player_turn(){
    if (current_name_turn == player_1){
        current_name_turn = player_2;
    } else if (current_name_turn == player_2){
        current_name_turn = player_1;
    }
}

void play_the_game(){
    display_board();
    while(game_is_playing){
        player_turn();
        switch_player_turn();
    }
}

int main()
{
    player_1 = ask_player_name_1(player_1);
    player_2 = ask_player_name_2(player_2);
    play_the_game();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `string current_name_turn = player_1;` initializes the variable to the value of `player_1`, which is *an empty string*.

Comment: It would have made more sense for you to create a simple `ask_player_name` and pass a simple `int` to denote the player number.  Instead you have repeated code, and pass a string that doesn't do anything except spin wheels.

Comment: @Eljay could you give me little example please?

Comment: `enum class Active { player_1, player_2 }; Active active_player = Active::player_1;` and use `active_player` as the discriminator, rather than a string to the active player's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working code that switches between the entered names:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool game_is_playing = true;
string name[] = {"x","o"};
string player_1, player_2;
string current_name_turn = player_1;

string ask_player_name_1(string player_1){
    cout << " Player 1's name: ";
    cin >> name[0];
    player_1 = name[0];
    current_name_turn = player_1;//added this line to set the current_name_turn
    return player_1;
}

string ask_player_name_2(string player_2){
    cout << " Player 2's name: ";
    cin >> name[1];
    player_2 = name[1];
    return player_2;
}

void display_board(){
    cout << player_1 + " (X) - (O) " + player_2 << endl;
}

void player_turn(){
    int position;
    cin.clear();
    cout << current_name_turn << "'s turn." << endl;
    cout << "Enter something: " << endl;
    cin >> position;
}

void switch_player_turn(){
    if (current_name_turn == player_1){
        current_name_turn = player_2;
    } else if (current_name_turn == player_2){
        current_name_turn = player_1;
    }
}

void play_the_game(){
    display_board();
    while(game_is_playing){
        player_turn();
        switch_player_turn();
    }
}

int main()
{
    player_1 = ask_player_name_1(player_1);
    player_2 = ask_player_name_2(player_2);
    play_the_game();
    return 0;
}
```

Below i removed some unnecessary repetition of code so that now you'll have a more compact version. In this compact version, you just have to pass the index of the players.

**Compact Version**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool game_is_playing = true;
string name[] = {"x","o"};
string player_1, player_2;
string current_name_turn = player_1;

//now we have one ask_player_name function instead of two which reduces the size of the program
string ask_player_name(int playerNumber){
    cout << " Player " <<playerNumber<<"'s name: ";
    cin >> name[playerNumber];
    current_name_turn = name[playerNumber];
    return name[playerNumber];
}
void display_board(){
    cout << player_1 + " (X) - (O) " + player_2 << endl;
}

void player_turn(){
    int position;
    cin.clear();
    cout << current_name_turn << "'s turn." << endl;
    cout << "Enter something: " << endl;
    cin >> position;
}

void switch_player_turn(){
    if (current_name_turn == player_1){
        current_name_turn = player_2;
    } else if (current_name_turn == player_2){
        current_name_turn = player_1;
    }
}

void play_the_game(){
    display_board();
    while(game_is_playing){
        player_turn();
        switch_player_turn();
    }
}

int main()
{
    player_1 = ask_player_name(0);
    player_2 = ask_player_name(1);
    play_the_game();
    return 0;
}
```